# Password Protecting a PDF

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, passwords, pdf-generation

I have an app in which I create a PDF file from the view, then email it. The code I'm using to generate the PDF (much thanks to casillic) is this:

```
- (void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; // this line

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cherry"];

    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

It is working perfectly. However, I would like to implement the ability to have the PDF password protected. So that if they email themselves the PDF, the will need to enter in a password in order to view it. I'm totally unsure of how to do this. I added in:

```
   NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = CFBridgingRelease(CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,
                                             &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                             &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks));
    CFDictionarySetValue((__bridge CFMutableDictionaryRef)(myDictionary), kCGPDFContextUserPassword, CFSTR("userpassword"));
    CFDictionarySetValue((__bridge CFMutableDictionaryRef)(myDictionary), kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, CFSTR("ownerpassword"));
```

I feel like I'm on the right track, but I'm totally unsure of what to do from here. I've read the docs about passcode protecting a PDF:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101
But these still go over my head.

If anyone knows how I need to modify this code to password protect the PDF, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the call to:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
```

by replacing the last parameter with `myDictionary`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, myDictionary);
```